# Lines between days in Calendar app month view are low contrast

Tags: calendar, ui

In the Mac Calendar.app, in the Month View, the lines between the days are practically INVISIBLE:

[image]

I have tried to increase the CONTRAST in the System Settings. But that did not make the lines better visible.

Here are my system settings:

[image]

How can I make the lines better visible?

Comment: AD can't answer *any* question on what or when (or anything else...) Apple will or will not do anything. This is strictly for "how do I fix..." questions. I have edited your question to remove the question about when Apple might fix your supposed bug.

Comment: Not liking Apple's color choices doesn't meant that it's a bug.

Comment: FORCING Apple's ridiculous pseudo-aesthetical color choice on users IS a mistake!

Comment: This could be a matter of screen profiling & calibration. To me, those lines are perfectly visible. Sure, they're low contrast, & increasing screen contrast won't help because they're less than 50% grey so will lighten rather than darken with increased contrast. Check your display profile is at least set to the correct one for your actual display. On older OSes from Display/Colour you can access manual calibration [idk if this is still in Monterey] - Hold Opt as you click to enable advanced mode - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUK5I.jpg

Comment: This is very strange: The lines are better visible when moving the Calendar window to my secondary external monitor! Can anyone explain this? But my primary external monitor has better quality than my second external monitor.

Comment: Different screens with different profiles exhibiting different gamma curves. It's all in the calibration/profiling.

Comment: These are the monitors from System Settings in Monterey:
monitor 1: https://i.imgur.com/K4UMeC1.png
monitor 2: https://i.imgur.com/PNJ5aih.png

Comment: This is the Profiles menu for the LG:
https://i.imgur.com/KF2mYKQ.png

Comment: Where does the PHL BDM3270 profile come from?

Comment: The PHL BDM3270 profile probably is from the PHL BDM3270 monitor. Is it potentially dangerous applying a profile from the list? Are the profiles stored on the physical monitor device?

Comment: Unless you're using a hardware colorimeter to profile, then you should always set each display's profile to the manufacturer's intended generic profile. For external displays that will have the manufacturer's name in it somewhere, for the internal it is often just something like 'Colour LCD' There used to be an option to "show only profiles for this display" which would narrow it right down. I've not used Monterey yet so idk where that option may have moved to.

Comment: But as you can see from my screenshots, the manufacturer profiles are already associated with the monitors. So what now?

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming one profile to be the internal screen. If the manufacturer's profile is miles out of true, then we're back to manual calibration [see above], or getting a hardware colorimeter.